# Create object,not to save before the end of the filling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Data collection for filling the order is going to table with 3 pages (go to each at the touch of a button). Stored in the database they need only after you press the last button. How to store data from the first to the last page?

1 page
`<%= form_for(@orders) do |f| %>

```
    <%= f.text_field :city,placeholder: "Город"%>

    <%= f.submit "Далее", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>`
```

2 page
`<%= form_for(@orders) do |f| %>

```
    <%= f.text_field :time, placeholder: "Время" %>

    <%= f.submit "Далее", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>`
```

3 page
`<%= form_for(@orders) do |f| %>

```
    <%= f.text_field :count, placeholder: "Количество" %>

    <%= f.text_field :phone,placeholder: "Телефон для связи"%>

    <%= f.submit "Заказать", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>`
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more detail for us to help you. What did you try?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36755930/edit) your question and add your code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could use the session or some other alternative storage mechanism actually saving the order in the database in the first step and performing the following steps as atomic update operations might be a much better solution.

The advantages are less complex logic and being able to avoid tricky chicken vs egg situations like for example how to route to a resource that does not have an id.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:draft, :confirmed, :processed, :shipped] # etc...
end
```

In this example you would use a bitmask column on the database - it should be set to zero by default an in the last step you would change the state of the order from `draft` to `confirmed`.

There are several gems such as [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) that are used to create wizards (step by step forms).

Yet another alternative is to use javascript to split a complex form into steps in the form of tabs or "slides" while the backend still processes it as a single operation.